# Create a dodged barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataset below:

```
Database<-c("Composite","DB","TC","RH","DGI","DCH","DCH","DCH","LDP")
Unique_Drugs<-c(12672,5130,1425,3090,6100,2019,250,736,1182)
Unique_Targets<-c(3987,2175,842,2308,2413,1441,198,327,702)
db<-data.frame(Database,Unique_Drugs,Unique_Targets)
```

and I would like to create a dodged bar chart like the picture below:
[image]

This plot came from a dataframe like:
[image]

The difference is that in the x-axis I want the 7 unique `Database` names and the `fill` argument should be the `Unique_Drugs` and `Unique_Targets` in order to create 2 colored bars that will display their values. Im not sure how to make it work.

My code is:

```
 p <- ggplot(data = db, aes(Database)) +
          geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), stat="count", aes(fill = colnames(db[2:4])), color = "black")+
          coord_flip()+
          theme(legend.position="top",
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                axis.title.x=element_text(size=18, face="bold", color="#000000"), # this changes the x axis title
                axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", color="#000000"), #This changes the x axis ticks text
                axis.title.y=element_text(size=18, face="bold", color="#000000"), # this changes the y axis title
                axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", color="#000000"))+ #This changes the y axis ticks text
          labs(x = "Database") +
          labs(y = "Value") +
          scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(factor(Database))) +
          scale_fill_manual("Databases", values = c("tomato","steelblue3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve what you want:

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(db), aes(x = Database, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + ylab(NULL) + theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_discrete(NULL, labels = c("Drugs", "Targets"))
```

[image]

If you wanted a bar plot only for drugs, there would be no need for `melt` as you could use `y = Unique_Drugs` to specify the bar heights (note that since we have heights we use `geom_col`). In this case, however, we want to specify two kinds of heights. Your words that *fill argument should be the `Unique_Drugs` and `Unique_Targets`* precisely suggest that we need some transformations because `ggplot` doesn't accept two variables for the same aesthetic. So, using `melt` we get all the heights as a single variable and get a single variable for `fill`.

Comment: exceptional answer. so the key is the melt (). thanks a lot!

Comment: @firmo23, no problem. That's right, I added some more comments.